# How to clean up geth data directory, perhaps moving more into freezer?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am running full geth 1.10.1 node; there is quite a large amount of data in active database and not nearly enough is moved into freezer db:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vdc        314G  255G   44G  86% /var/lib/geth/data
/dev/vdd        472G  197G  251G  44% /var/lib/geth/data/geth/chaindata/ancient
```

Questions are:

- is there any way I could migrate more data from active set into freezer?
- is there another way to safely prune the active database to reduce amount of data?